# apply dbSeeChanges to all recordsets VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, odbc

I am using MS access 2016 as a front end and have ODBC to a microsoft SQL server.

When i open a recordset in VBA i got the "You must use the dbSeeChanges option with OpenRecordSet..."

Now i have resolved this issue, so my question is this: Is there an easy way to apply this to all places where a recordset is created? Is there some simple setting to check in VBA? Because there are a lot of recordsets that get made throughout my code and adding the dbSeeChanges command everywhere will take a long time.

In case someone wants the fix for the dbSeeChanges:

```
Set tempRcst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM table1", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
```

Comment: There is no easy way - but I wonder how you came this far before meeting that message.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way would be to cut the text

,dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges

Into your cut/paste buffer.

You then do a global search on OpenRecordSet(

When you find a match (hit f3 for search). When you see a match, then tap “end” key to move to end of line, then one back arrow, and then a ctrl-v to paste in above. Now hit f3 and do this again (and again etc.).

The above process will occur quite rapid – even in a large application the above will only take a few minutes. You could I suppose use some VBA to read all code and modify, but I think the above process would be faster than working out some VBA to do a global type of replace on the code.

So you can do a global search, but no "pattern" match replace is available in the VBA IDE.

Comment: yeah, thats pretty much the process i followed!! Thanks for the post!